# how do I pass table row id to next view?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a table view controller that displays json data from a web api, a list of lists.  I want to drill down into the selected list when the user clicks that row.  I can't seem to figure out how to pass the list id to the next view controller.

Here is the struct for the list of shipments in the first view

```
struct Shipments: Codable {
  var result: [Shipment]
}

struct Shipment: Codable {
  var ListID: String
  var ShowName: String
  var Booth: String
  var ShipDate: String
  var ShipVia: String
  var Weight: String
}
```

I pass the selected row to the next view controller like this:

```
var ShipListID = [Shipment]()
....
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let vc = ShippingUnitsTableViewController()
    vc.ShipListID = [ShipLists[indexPath.row]]
    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

}
```

Here is the result of printing the info passed to the next view controller

```
[Test.Shipment(ListID: "8", Name: "BIG SHOW 2020 Las Vegas", Booth: "212", ShipDate: "2019-09-21", ShipVia: "sv", Weight: "3795.00")]
```

How do I access the value of ListID in the second view controller?

Comment: “How do I access the value of ListID in the second view controller?” It is `self.ShipListID.ListID`.

Comment: start variable names with small letter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Send an array of type `Shipment` with `[ShipLists[indexPath.row]]`  while you need to either send it like `ShipLists[indexPath.row]` or `ShipLists[indexPath.row].listID` and declare in destination  `var shipment:Shipment?` or `var shipListID:String?` respectively

```
 vc.shipListID = ShipLists[indexPath.row].listID
```

Destination vc like

```
class ShippingUnitsTableViewController:UITableViewController {
   var shipListID:String? 
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       print(shipListID)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to access it in the view controller of the pushed view controller.

for example:
in viewDidLoad() of ShippingUnitsTableViewController

```
print(self.shipListID.ListID)
```